# String format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-formatting

I'd like to format a number and remove starting 0s from it. e.g.:
`001 => 1`

`10 => 10`

Actually, I have a jQuery method which does the following:

```
  $('#myelement').text($('#myElement').text()+1);
```

When the element's text is `0`, the function makes it `01`, How can I make it to show `1` using jQuery or javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need:

```
parseInt($('#myElement').text(), 10) + 1;
```

what you're asking for:

```
($('#myElement').text()+1).replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Comment: Hence the "what you're asking for" predicate.  The original question said "I'd like to format a string..."

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string too, but it is aware of rounding rules. For example.

Comment: `toFixed` is on numbers, not strings.  If you literally want to remove leading zeros from a ___string___, my answer is correct

Comment: I see your point now, please edit your answer a little so I can upvote it.

Comment: @cwolvesL: Just What I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseInt("0010", 10).toString()`. Ignore `toString()` if you need the `int` only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to increment the value, convert the current text in to a number using unary `+`:

```
$('#myelement').text(function(i, v){
    return +v + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+"0001" //1
```

See above! .......

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myelement').text(parseInt($('#myElement').text(), 10) + 1);
```